# mod_rewrite and redirecting on exact match

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I want to redirect http://www.name.com and http://name.com/ to http://my.name.com/.

Examples
http://www.name.com/ goes to http://my.name.com
http://name.com/ goes to http://my.name.com
http://www.name.com/picture.jpg no redirect
http://name.com/folder/picture.jpg no redirect

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more information about your setup would be good, but essentially:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://my.name.com/ [R=301,L]
```

That's for in your virtual host configs for the domains that are redirecting; if it's in an htaccess or `<Directory>` block then you'll need to remove path information:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://my.name.com/ [R=301,L]
```

..and if it's in a location like an htaccess that applies to all of the domain names, then you'll need to have it not redirect for the target domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://my.name.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't this redirect everything to my.name.com?  I'm looking to only redirect when the URL is exactly http://www.name.com or http://name.com

Comment: @Michael Nope!  My match string in the first one is `^/$` - it must be an ***exact*** match, with the start and end of the string directing preceding and following the slash.  Within a `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context, the directory path is stripped, so a request for `http://name.com/` comes in to `mod_rewrite`'s match process as an empty string, which is exactly what `^$` will match in the second and third examples.